# Angular 9 MatExpansionModule could not be resolved

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';

I also have MatExpansionModule in my imports and it's crashing.

Did I do something wrong or is there a problem with @angular/material?

The other add is in app.module.ts but that was just attempt of a solution read on github - obviously it did not work.

[dashboard module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VcKo.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8YRh.png)

Comment: Please show us all the Modules you're declaring it in. It looks like you're declaring it in 3 modules. Show us the code, and show us the error message in text, not in a screenshot please.

Comment: There, added @Train

Comment: And you've installed Angular Material within your app with your package manager?

Comment: @AdamDunkerley yes

Answer (score 1):

Deleted node_modules folder and ran 'npm install'. It's working now.